# MobileNet Confusion Matrix

Tags: neural-network

I'm facing an issue while following the MarkDaoust's gitHub repository: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2

What I've done is creating a mobilenet model which classify different classes, creating the retrained_graph.pb and retrained_labels.txt

The problem is that I'm not able to create a confusion matrix for all the classes. I've tried to use the script evaluate.py but it's no use, even the tf.confusion_matrix is useless because I don't know which are the images in the test set/training_test (I just know how many images will be picked from each class folder).

I hope there is a function or something that, given the retrained_graph.pb can give me the confusion matrix, otherwise I should do all manually because the script retrain can print all the misclassified images from test set but it would be a huge work to be done manually.